# Is there an analogue of this linear-eigenvalue problem result to the nonlinear case?

Tags: nonlinear-eigenvalue

Sorry, I don't know the name of the result or if there is one, but I know that for an operator $A$ with for which $(A - \lambda I)^{-1}$ is bounded and normal for $\lambda \notin \sigma(A)$, we have

$ \| (A - \lambda I)^{-1} \|_\infty = \frac{1}{\text{dist}(\lambda,~ \sigma(A))}$

Does anyone know if there is an analogous result for nonlinear eigenvalue problems, e.g. $R(\lambda) = B\lambda^2 + C \lambda + D$ for matrices $B, C,$ and $D$? Can I say something about $\|R(\lambda)^{-1}\|$?

Comment: Please clarify. Do you really mean "nonlinear"? What is $A(\lambda)$? How can the equality in the first display hold, when the left is independent of $\lambda$ and the right is not? How does the result work for $A=0$? What does $\mathrm{dist}(\lambda,A)$ even mean assuming that $\lambda$ is a complex number and $A$ is an operator? What norms are you considering?

Comment: Shoot, sorry about that. I was used to using the notation for nonlinear eigenvalue problems. An example (called a quadratic eigenvalue problem) is to find nontrivial $(\lambda, x)$ pairs such that $R(\lambda) x = 0$ where $R(\lambda)$ is defined in the post.

Comment: Unless you are willing to assume that B,C and D commute, it is unlikely that you will be able to say much.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy do you know a result when they do commute? Really I am looking at differential operators acting on smooth functions, so oftentimes they do commute.

My thought was that there may be a result even when B, C, and D do not commute, using the equivalence of the spectrum of the NL problem with its linearization. I have an idea on how to proceed, but I did not want to try to reinvent the wheel if a result exists.

Comment: If they commute, can't you factorize and do partial fraction decomposition?